# How to let the user select Bar Graph - Series parameter dynamically on Superset

Tags: bar-chart, apache-superset

I've a dataset with multiple classifications for the items as below

```
item   |  class_1  |  class_2  |  class_3
-----------------------------------------
item_1 |  type_1a  |  type_2a  |  type_3a 
item_2 |  type_1b  |  type_2b  |  type_3b
item_3 |  type_1a  |  type_2b  |  type_3c
```

On Superset I'm creating a BarGraph which shows the count as below
X-axis - Classification type and Y-axis - Count of Items

[image: Bar Graph with one classification]

Since there are multiple classifications available, I should be able to select the type and correspondingly the chart should show the bar graph for that type of classification on X-axis

I've considered going for stacked distribution but that gives a clumsy experience.

Is there any way that I can let User select the X-Axis Parameter and then show the corresponding chart?

Comment: Why not use a filter for x-axis? Also, if your sample table matches the chart image it would be easier to understand the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

In the chart editor your end-user should be able to select the X-axis from a list of columns (class_1, class_2,...). You can edit your datasource to only display "groupable" columns (columns allowed in the X-axis) if you so choose.

You could always save two versions of the chart (one for each X-axis variable) to a dashboard.